# Beginner help: Why does my view have an error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner in Ruby on rails and programming in general and I am making a very basic Todo List application.

My problem is that I am receiving the error message:

> /home/brian/Desktop/rails_projects/to_do_list/app/views/lists/index.html.erb:20: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

I think this means that I haven't either closed off an html tag or haven't put <% end %> somewhere, but could be wrong. It seems like an easy fix and have double checked my code and it appears that all tags are closed and that I have ended my ruby line.

Here is my view template in /app/views/lists/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Your To-Do Lists:</h1>

<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Title:</th>
    <th>Complete by:</th>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @lists.each.do |list| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= list.title %></td>
        <td><%= list.complete_by %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

Also if it is helpful, here is /app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @lists = List.all
  end

end
```

and /db/migrate/create_lists.rb

```
class CreateLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lists do |t|
        t.string :title
        t.date :complete_by

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you for your time,

Brian

Comment: did that help solve your issue  @Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `"."` between the `.each` method and the `do` block:

```
<h1>Your To-Do Lists:</h1>

<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Title:</th>
    <th>Complete by:</th>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @lists.each do |list| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= list.title %></td>
        <td><%= list.complete_by %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

Otherwise this looks good!

Comment: Oh man, i'm kicking myself already. Thanks again for the help @Cyzanfar